# Generate numbers from two gaussians in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am new to this so please bear with me. I am trying to generate data points from a mixture of gaussians model with the following parameters:

```
mixGaussTrue.mean = [-1 1.5];
mixGaussTrue.cov = reshape([0.5 0.25],1,1,2);
```

Now I have a variable, h that determines which gaussian to use. So h is either 1 (first gaussian) or 2. So say for e.g. if h is 1, how do I generate values from the first gaussian, with mean -1 and covariance 0.5 ?

I cannot use build in functions and meant to be writing the equation for the gaussians.

So I have

```
for i=1:300
    if h==1 
        data(1,i) = ( 1/( sqrt( 2*pi*mixGaussTrue.cov(:,:,1) ) ) ) * exp( - (((cData - 
        mixGaussTrue.mean(1,1))^2)/(2* mixGaussTrue.cov(:,:,1))) ) ;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What code have you written so far and where is the problem? This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: It is, i just want to be pointed in the right direction. 

So I have 
for i=1:300
    if h==1
        data(1,i) = (  1/(  sqrt( 2*pi*mixGaussTrue.cov(:,:,1) ) )  ) * exp(   - (((cData - mixGaussTrue.mean(1,1))^2)/(2* mixGaussTrue.cov(:,:,1)))    )   ;

Comment: It would be best to add that to the question.

Comment: Done. Plz see updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your two Gaussians are one-dimensional.

Anyway, you can use `randn()` which generate a random Gaussian variable:

```
data(i)=mixGaussTrue.cov(h)*randn()+mixGaussTrue.mean(h)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I cant use randn i think and I'm meant to write the code for the gaussian distribution.

Comment: What do you mean? Why can't you use `randn`?

Comment: The tutorial says you should NOT be using functions like normpdf and
 normfit or other functions from Statistics Toolbox in sampling from or fitting your distributions.

Comment: Also, do you mind explaining what you wrote above please? Thanks!

Comment: Okay. You should undersand this: I spend time on this website to help engineers with real problems. Not do do your homework in your place. I will not update my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate your effort in helping me.